# Openai python api and Firestore emulator not playing well together

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, openai-api

wondering if anyone else has seen this bizarre behavior.

The python script below is a simplified version of something that I'm deploying to Cloud Run. The emulator stuff is replaced by `client = firestore.Client()` in the deployed app, and that works fine. The problem only pertains to using the firestore emulator for local dev.

I run the emulator:

```
$ gcloud beta emulators firestore start --project test --host-port 'localhost:8001'
```

I run the script:

```py
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import google.auth
from google.cloud import firestore
import mock

PORT = "8001"

os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = f"localhost:{PORT}"
os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH"] = f"localhost:{PORT}/firestore"
os.environ["FIRESTORE_HOST"] = f"http://localhost:{PORT}/firestore"
os.environ["FIRESTORE_DATASET"] = "streamlit_firestore"
os.environ["FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID"] = "test"
credentials = mock.Mock(spec=google.auth.credentials.Credentials)
fs_client = firestore.Client(project="test", credentials=credentials)

key = open("secrets/azure-openai-key1.txt").read().strip()
oai_client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint="https://azeastus2ai001.openai.azure.com/",
    api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
    api_key=key,
)

# ARBITRARY WRITE TO FIRESTORE
coll = fs_client.collection("fake@uhoh.com")
ref = coll.document()
ref.set({'base': 'jumping'})

# THIS HANGS
response = oai_client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-35-turbo-16k-1",
    messages=[
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant.'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': 'hello'}
    ],
    temperature=0.5
)

message_full = response.choices[0].message
print(message_full.content)
```

and the script just hangs on the `openai.ChatCompletion.create` call. ^C doesn't stop the script. When I close the terminal running the script, the emulator issues this warning to the console:

```
[firestore] Nov 20, 2023 6:22:04 PM io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline onUnhandledInboundException
[firestore] WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
[firestore] java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[firestore]     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
[firestore]     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
[firestore]     at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:256)
[firestore]     at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[firestore]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
[firestore]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
[firestore]     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[firestore]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
[firestore]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

If I comment out the "ARBITRARY WRITE TO FIRESTORE" part, the script runs to completion.

So I guess there's some kind of cross-talk between openai's python lib and the firestore emulator. Changing the port doesn't help - I tried 8002 and some random number in the ten thousands.

```
% gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 452.0.0
alpha 2023.10.23
app-engine-python 1.9.107
beta 2023.10.23
bq 2.0.98
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.1
cloud-firestore-emulator 1.18.2
core 2023.10.23
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.5.6
gsutil 5.26
kubectl 1.27.5
```

Python package openai version is 1.3.3
(UPDATE: a month ago when I originally posted it was 0.27.8. I tried this with 1.1.2 as 1.2.4 as well.)

Running on Mac OS Sonoma 14.0

Comment: I just tried running the emulator in docker, and that works

Comment: I've noticed it works for me, unless I update to the latest openai lib (1.3.3) at which point the firebase functions keep hanging up

Comment: @ByronCoetsee I just tried some newer versions and the script still hangs. I've updated the code in the question for 1.x api.