# Calling OpenAI hangs when using Firestore emulator

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, openai-api, firebase-tools

I am trying to build some code that will run as a Firebase function.  The code will call OpenAI and then write the results to Firestore.  However, when I try to run the code using the Firebase emulator, it is hanging.  I have trimmed it down to the following minimal example.  Any thoughts on how to work around this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I am running Mac OS 14.0 and Python 3.11.8.  I also tried Python 3.12.2.

This seems to be very similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377614/openai-python-api-and-firestore-emulator-not-playing-well-together), maybe even the same.  But no answer was posted, so hoping for more input.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import os
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, firestore
import openai

# Configure Firestore to use the emulator

os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = 'localhost:8080'
app = initialize_app()

# Note: You will need to replace "your-project-id" with your own project id
db = firestore.Client(project="your-project-id")

# Configure OpenAI

# Note: You will need to provide a valid OpenAI API key
OPENAI_API_KEY = "sk-..."
OPENAI_MODEL = "gpt-4"
messages = [{"role": "system", 
             "content": "You are an intelligent AI assistant."}, 
            {"role": "user", 
            "content": "Write python to code to generate the first 100 prime numbers."}]

# If the following line is uncommented, then the program will hang indefinitely.
# If the following line is commented out, then the program will run to completion
# after about 15 seconds.
db.collection("test").add({"test": "test"})   ### COMMENT OUT THIS LINE TO AVOID HANGING
openai_client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
response = openai_client.chat.completions.create(
    model=OPENAI_MODEL,
    messages=messages,
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```